# How do I copy an object value from a mutable array into a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

How do I copy an object value from a mutable array into a string?

The array holds objects from parsed XML, but now I cannot copy the array value into a string.

How can I do this?

Comment: What class are the objects in the array?

Comment: Some code where we can see what you are trying to do may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNumber has a stringValue message, which returns the object as an NSString:

```
NSString *foo = [myNSNumber stringValue];
```

Alternately, if you have a primitive value like NSUInteger, or a float, you can use NSString directly:

```
NSUInteger nsuint = 20;
CGFloat fff = 21.0;

NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)nsuint];
```

//or

```
NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",fff];
```

Ole's question stands, however. One way to find out might be to iterate through the array asking for descriptions:

```
int count = 0;
for (id item in myMutableArray) {
    count +=1;
    NSLog(@"Item %d is a %@", count, [item description]");
}
```

This doesn't always yield intelligent results, but often does.

Comment: I've edited the format specifiers to be consistent across 32-64 bit environments as described in the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)